# How to call postgres stored procedure from golang using gorm package

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I was working on a **golang** project, I've used a **postgres** database to store data with some **Stored Procedure.**

> I used github.com/jinzhu/gorm for connecting to the database.

I used below query to retrieve data. I know in postgres we are unable to use select, so I only tried insert code in SP.

```
db.Database.Raw("CALL mydatabase.mystoredprocedure('" + param1 + "','" + param2 + "')")

db.Database.Raw("SELECT * FROM table1").Scan(&tableValue)
```

But here I'm only able to call a SELECT statement, not able to call the stored procedure.

Please, can any one help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using functions instead of procedures because functions can be invoked with `SELECT`. Also your procedure call is subject to sql injection, you might want to be more careful.

Answer (score 11):

`db.Database.Raw(...)` alone does not do anything, it needs to be chained with `Scan`. If you are not expecting any results, use `Exec`:

```golang
db.Database.Exec("CALL mydatabase.mystoredprocedure($1, $2)", param1, param2)
```